# Finding the rank of a linear map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

In the textbook that I am working through, it is left as an exercise to prove the following claim

> Consider two linear maps $P$ and $Q$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ (for $m \le n$) such that $P$ is an injective linear map. If we assume that the first $m$ columns of P are linearly independent, then we need to show that $\exists \delta >0$ such that $$ \lvert \lvert Q-P \rvert \rvert < \delta \implies rank(Q) = m$$ where our choice of norm is the operator norm.

This exercise is supposed to be equivalent to showing that the set of matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ that have full rank form an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$

As someone that doesn't have a math background, I find these types (epsilon-delta) of proofs particularly challenging, as I often find them difficult to build up an intuition for. As there are no solutions to the exercises, I would be grateful for any guidance here on how to prove the statement.

Comment: If u assume $P$ is injective, then necessarily $n\leq m$? (not the reverse inequality, or is it an extra hypothesis, I mean m=n?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only assume that $m$ columns of $P$ are linearly independent, i.e $P$ is surjective (Since the columns of $P$ spans its image), So there's some linear map $T:\mathbb{R} ^{m} \to \mathbb{R} ^{n} $ such that $PT=I$, So $P+Q^{*} =P(I+TQ^{*} )$, Now we apply the following :$$ $$  lemma :if $S:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R} ^{n} $ is a Linear map, such that $\lvert \lvert S\rvert \rvert <1$,then $I+S$ is invertible (an isomorphism). $$ $$ if we choose $\lvert \lvert Q^{*} \rvert \rvert <\lvert \lvert T \rvert \rvert <\frac{1}{\lvert \lvert T\rvert \rvert} $, then $\lvert \lvert TQ* \rvert \rvert <1$,So (by our lemma), $I+TQ^{*} $ is invertible, hence $rank(P+Q) =m$, now the proof is finished by putting $Q=P+Q^{*} $(remark that $||P-Q||=||Q{*} ||$, with $\delta=\frac{1}{\lvert \lvert T\rvert \rvert}$
This shows that the set of linear maps having full rank is open, i. e if $P$ has a full rank, and $Q$ is close enough $(\lvert \lvert P-Q\rvert \rvert <\delta $) , then $Q$ still have full rank.

Comment: @FD_bfa sorry for the bad notation, $Q"$ is a linear map, which denotes $P-Q=Q"$

Comment: @FD_bfa u are welcome, I edited the post by changing $Q"$ into $Q^{*} $, hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Second proof
Remark that my first proof is more general in that it shows that the set of right invertible linear continous maps(linear maps $P:X\mapsto Y$ such that there's Some continous $T:Y\to X$ such that $PT=I$) between two normed spaces is open. $$ $$
$P$ has $m$ linearly independent columns iff there's some minor (detrrminent of a square m×m sub-matrix) is not zero, Since the determinznt (any minor) is a continuous map(polynomial in the entries), there's a $\delta$ such that if $||P-Q||<\delta $, $Q$ has a non-vanishing $m$-minor, i.e $Q$ has $m$ linearly independent columns, equivelently $Rank(Q) =m$