# Openness of the determinant of a general linear group

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have been working through a linear algebra textbook and came across the following problem.

> Consider $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $P$ is invertible (ie. det$(P) \neq 0$). Show that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ where det($P+tQ) \neq 0$ for all $t \in (- \epsilon , \epsilon)$.

I can't see why this holds. Particularly as Q is not invertible, this feels intuitively difficult for me to understand. I would be grateful for a proof or an intuition as to why this is the case.

Comment: [Your previuos post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570329/finding-the-rank-of-a-linear-map) is helpful here, which states that (in the special case of $m=n$) if $P$ is invertible then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $R$ is invertible as long as $\|R-P\|<\epsilon$; now, take $\delta=\frac\epsilon{\|Q\|}$, then for all $t\in(-\delta,\delta)$ we have $\|P+tQ-P\|<\epsilon$, so $P+tQ$ is invertible.

Comment: $\|P+tQ-P\|=|t|\cdot\|Q\|<\delta\|Q\|=\epsilon$, recalling that $|t|<\delta$ and the definition of $\delta$.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of the formula $A^{-1}=\frac{\text{adj}(A)}{\det (A)}$, where $\text{adj}(A)$ is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$. The computations may not be that easy. You can start with $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: It follows from the definition of $\text{adj}(A)$, which is some linear combinations of determinants of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices, hence is a summation of some $(n-1)$-polynomials. Try some computations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is exactly the continuity of the determinent ,are u familiar with the fact that if a continous function doesn't vanish at a point , it still doesn't vanish in a neighborhood of that point?to Prove continuity,one can mention that the determinent (as a map :$\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}\to \mathbb{R}$)is a polynomial.Another approach is to use  the lemma I mentionned in my other answer $$\lvert \lvert S\rvert \rvert <1 \implies Det(I+S)\neq 0 $$ $$P+tQ=P(I+tP^{-1}Q) $$Since the product of two invertible operators is invertible , it suffice to show that $(I+tP^{-1}Q)$ is invertible,this is done by using our lemma ,where $S=tP^{-1}Q$,So we only need  $\lvert \lvert tP^{-1}Q \rvert \rvert=\lvert t\rvert \lvert \lvert P^{-1}Q \rvert \rvert<1$ or quivalently ($Q\neq 0$)
$\lvert t\rvert <\frac{1}{\lvert \lvert P^{-1}Q \rvert \rvert}$ (i.e $\delta=\frac{1}{\lvert \lvert P^{-1}Q \rvert \rvert})$,of course the case $Q=0$ is trivial since the statement is true for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$.